# Query-Term and Filter-Term Return Zero Results on an Exact Match, but Query-Match Returns a Result. Why?

Tags: elasticsearch

Given:

- I loaded an instance into ElasticSearch which has its `placeId` property set to `"Foo"`.
- And I run the following searches:

  ```
  {
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "placeId": {
          "value": "Foo"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  {
    "filter": {
      "term": {
        "placeId": "Foo"
      }
    }
  }

  {
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "placeId": {
          "query": "Foo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

But of these three, only the third one returned a result.

Why is this? Shouldn't they all have returned a result?

Comment: I don't know your Elastic search data. please can you update the elastic search data with Your Question.

Comment: @Bass: Bullet point #1 is my data. Assume that I have some data with one instance which has placeId = "Foo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u are not used an analyzer means elastic search term query and term query Filter should not support the Upper case Value. Please use "foo" in Your Query.  please use this way

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/index/incident/_search -d '{
"query":{
"term":{"field1":{"value":"value1"}
}}}'
```

but match all query is support upper and lower case.
Hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

By default, using the standard analyzer, ES places your "Foo" in an index as "foo" (meaning, lowercased). When searching for `term`, ES doesn't use an analyzer so, it is actually searching for "Foo" (exact case). Whereas, in its index the "foo" exists (because of the analyzer).

The value passed for `match` instead is analyzed and ES is actually searching for "foo" in its indices, not "Foo" as it does with `term`.

So, the behavior you see is normal and this is how it's supposed to work.
[Here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) about `match`:

> A family of match queries that accept text/numerics/dates, **analyzes it**, and constructs a query out of it.

[Here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) about `term`:

> Matches documents that have fields that contain a term (**not analyzed**).